# How to retrieve whole data from $$ROOT after using unwind in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework, unwind

I am trying to group data using mongodb aggregation method.
I have no idea about the DB structure but email column will be there. In DB email column can be saved with any name like gmail, mail, etc. For example test DB is shown below.
How to group by email column if we don't know the name present in DB

```
    {
      "name": "stuv",
      "email": "xyz@gmail.in",
      "phone": "12345678990" 
    },
    {
     
      "name": "pqr",
      "email": "abc@gmail.com",
      "phone": "9876543210"
     
    },
    {
      "name": "xyz",
      "email": "xyz@gmail.in",
      "phone": "2345678901"
    
    },
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "email": "abc@gmail.com",
      "phone": "4567890123"
      
    }
```

From the above DB, I want to group data by unknown column name email so I am unwinding data and matching value with email regex and  grouping the data and pushing root data to dups as shown below.

```
  db.test.aggregate([
    
  {$project: {_id: 0}},
 
  {$project: {data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"}}},

 { $unwind: "$data"},

  {$group: {_id: "$data.v", 
  
      dups:{ $push: "$data"},
      count: { "$sum": 1 }   

    }},
    
    { $match: { "_id": /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/ }  },

])
```

From the above aggregate function after using  unwind I am not getting  all fields(name, phone, email) inside dups instead I am getting  only grouped field i.e, email column in the  form of key and  value separately as shown in the below output. I want output like email:abc@gmail.com along with all other fields as shown in expected output result.

**MY OUTPUT:**

```
 "result": [
        {
            "_id": "abc@gmail.com",
            "dups": [
                {
                    "k": "email",
                    "v": "abc@gmail.com"
                },
                {
                    "k": "email",
                    "v": "abc@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "_id": "xyz@gmail.in",
            "dups": [
                {
                    "k": "email",
                    "v": "xyz@gmail.in"
                },
                {
                    "k": "email",
                    "v": "xyz@gmail.in"
                }
            ],
            "count": 2
        }
    ]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
"result": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "email": "abc@gmail.com"
            },
            "dups": [
                {
                    "_id": "62af2c14e50225b659ab68a4",
                    "name": "pqr",
                    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
                    "phone": "9876543210"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "62af2c14e50225b659ab68a6",
                    "name": "abc",
                    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
                    "phone": "4567890123"
                }
            ],
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "email": "xyz@gmail.in"
            },
            "dups": [
                {
                    "_id": "62af2c14e50225b659ab68a3",
                    "name": "stuv",
                    "email": "xyz@gmail.in",
                    "phone": "12345678990"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "62af2c14e50225b659ab68a5",
                    "name": "xyz",
                    "email": "xyz@gmail.in",
                    "phone": "2345678901"
                }
            ],
            "count": 2
        }
    ]
```

Kindly help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: You want to continue from the stage you left or could use a better query?

Comment: To save from a lot of headache, here is your fixed email regex: `/^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*\.\w{2,3}$/`

Comment: @Gibbs To continue the existing query or if you suggest new query anything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:
One option is to keep the current data and to it the array of keys and values, here as `mailData`.
Then we can extract the email value using `$regexMatch` and `$reduce` to use it at the `$group` step as the `_id`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {mailData: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"}, data: "$$ROOT"}},
  {
    $set: {
      mailData: {
        $first: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$mailData",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $regexMatch: {
                        input: {$toString: "$$this.v"},
                        regex: /^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*\.\w{2,3}$/
                      }
                    },
                    ["$$this.v"],
                    []
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$mailData",
      dups: {$push: "$data"},
      count: {"$sum": 1}
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MH0Gyh9OxtC)

Another option is similar to your attempt, but using `$regexMatch` and group afterwards:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {mailData: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"}, data: "$$ROOT"}},
  {$unwind: "$mailData"},
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {$regexMatch: {
              input: {$toString: "$mailData.v"},
              regex: /^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*\.\w{2,3}$/
            }
          }, true
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$mailData.v",
      dups: {$push: "$data"},
      count: {"$sum": 1}
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - unwind](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8nk9HmDBdck)

Comment: \\ I don't know the column name which is stored in DB. The  email column can be saved with any name like mail, gmailcompany, etc. So to get value from root I am using $objectToArray and $unwind and then matching with  email regex.

Comment: Updated accordingly

Comment: Thankyou. But, I dont know the DB structure, any fields can be present in DB not only the fields I mentioned in DB structure like name, phone, email etc. Without knowing field names I can't push with into dups.

Comment: Try it now. Updated again

Comment: Thankyou so much. It is working as expected.